# How to run Flutter Web in Android native Webview application?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, webview, flutter-web

I am trying to display the flutter web application using Webview from the native Android. However the page is show the blank page.

Here is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var webView: WebView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.webview_test)
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    webView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

    webView.loadUrl("http://localhost:5011/#/login")

}
```

The web application works fine in the emulator browser.

There are errors from the Webview browser in the Android app:

> 022-10-19 09:53:02.040 21184-21184/com.example.kotlinwebview
> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(82)] "Loading app from service worker.",
> source: http://localhost:5011/ (82) 2022-10-19 09:53:24.678
> 21184-21184/com.example.kotlinwebview I/chromium:
> [INFO:CONSOLE(52119)] "registerExtension() from dart:developer is only
> supported in build/run/test environments where the developer event
> method hooks have been set.", source:
> http://localhost:5011/dart_sdk.js (52119) 2022-10-19 09:53:25.370
> 21184-21184/com.example.kotlinwebview I/chromium:
> [INFO:CONSOLE(52101)] "postEvent() from dart:developer is only
> supported in build/run/test environments where the developer event
> method hooks have been set.", source:
> http://localhost:5011/dart_sdk.js (52101) 2022-10-19 09:53:25.453
> 21184-21184/com.example.kotlinwebview I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5067)]
> "Uncaught (in promise) Error", source:
> http://localhost:5011/dart_sdk.js (5067) 2022-10-19 09:53:25.453
> 21184-21184/com.example.kotlinwebview I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5067)]
> "Uncaught (in promise) Error", source:
> http://localhost:5011/dart_sdk.js (5067

Is there any configuration that needs to be set for running the Flutter web application in the Android native Webview?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a package that can easily manage your code and save time.

Package link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

In-App Browser using Chrome Custom Tabs on Android / SFSafariViewController on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do it not from a native Android app, but from a Flutter app compiled from Android. Luckily, a Flutter WebView can render a webpage made with Flutter Web.